# How can I save and display date picker value in detail text label using core data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, core-data, datepicker

I have a simple reminder app using core data, with 2 entities, one for 'details' of the reminder and one for the 'date' of the reminder. The user adds a reminder and picks a date and that is then stored in a table view of all of their reminders.

I have the 'details' entity value saving correctly from the text field into the label of the table view but I can't seem to get the date to save from the date picker and into the detail text label of the table view.

In the EnterReminderViewController.m:

```
-(void)insertReminderDetails {

CoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
ReminderEntry *entry = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ReminderEntry" inManagedObjectContext:coreDataStack.managedObjectContext];

entry.details = self.reminderTextField.text;
entry.date =  self.datePicker;


[coreDataStack saveContext];

}
```

And in UpcomingRemindersTableViewController.m:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

ReminderEntry *entry = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.textLabel.text = entry.details;

 cell.detailTextLabel.text = entry.date;

return cell;
```

}

Do I need to convert the value to a string for this to work? Also, do I need to create a separate fetch request for the date?

Comment: What is `self.datePicker`? What kind of object?

Comment: Sorry. I have datePicker property connected in my storyboard so I was trying that. That element is not working. I'm getting an error when I run the app: 'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "date"; desired type = NSDate; given type = UIDatePicker; value = <UIDatePicker:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first code snippet, your `entry.date` property appears to be a Core Data "date" attribute, which is equivalent to an `NSDate` in code. You're attempting to assign a `UIDatePicker` to it. That's incorrect, because `UIDatePicker` is a UI control that lets the user select a date, it's not a date in itself. You need to ask the date picker for its current date value-- probably `self.datePicker.date` in your code.

In your second code snippet, you appear to be assigning `entry.date` to a `UILabel` text attribute. That's also incompatible, because dates are not strings. A simple fix would be to use `entry.date.description`, but that will use GMT rather than local time. To get more control over converting a date to a string, look into `NSDateFormatter`.

Answer (score 0):

You can able to set attribute  values as date to transform then save date picker date as init .and we have to take date picker date as NS Date not string in core date .Hope it will help You .